# Javadoc : document value of static final enum reference

Tags: java, javadoc

Let's say I have:

```java
public enum Color {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    YELLOW
}
```

Then elsewhere in my code I have

```java
public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.RED;
```

Now I would like to document to readers of my Javadoc what the value of `DEFAULT_COLOR` is (of course without repeating myself). How to do that?

The problem being - as I see it - that such reference (although declared `static final` and pointing to an enum) will *not* show up in Javadoc's "constant-values.html". I see no technical reason why it shouldn't but as far as I can tell it doesn't. Perhaps I've simply misunderstood?

#### Refinement

To be precise the question is about `static final` declarations of an Enum variable where the right-hand-side is a single identifier as defined by the JLS, thus excluding cases where the RHS is a more complex expression. This is similar to the current Javadoc behavior for assignments of primitive types where Javadoc will not try to render if the RHS isn't a so-called 'constant expression'. We can surely expect Javadoc to do the same can-I-render-this-unambigiusly? analysis for Enums, no?. By saying the RHS must be a single identifier we limit ourselves to something which - IMO - should be unambiguously renderable for Javadoc.

Comment: There _is_ a technical reason - unlike `1`, `"hello"` or `0.5f`, `Color.RED` is not a compile time constant.

Comment: Really? Perhaps not formally a compile-time constant from the Java spec, but for all practical purposes an Enum is indeed a compile-time constant, no? I don't see why Javadoc cannot "resolve" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment already said, only if the value is a compile time constant does javadoc render it (and very few things are - `true`, `false`, number literals, string constants is where it starts. Operators where all operands are constants are also constant. Then any static final field that is initialized with such a constant is itself constant. Thus, `static final int foo = SOME_OTHER_FIELD + YET_ANOTHER + 5;` can be constant.

That means Color.RED isn't a constant and thus isn't shown.

It's not just a matter of 'resolving things', it's a matter of rendering.

Imagine you wrote this:

```
private static final List<String> COUNTRIES = List.of(... all 300-or-so countries here_);
```

should the entire list be injected into the javadoc? Hopefully this example makes it clear that the answer isn't always 'yes', and it is not really feasible to draw a line.

Even if the answer is yes, how do you propose the javadoc renders this information? Just take the raw source code and dump it straight into the html? Take the raw source code, and auto-reformat it? What other options exist?

Javadoc can't assume it can resolve the expression. Imagine the expression is:

```
public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Math.random() > 0.5 ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE;
```

That should make it clear that you have no feasible options to render non-CTCs in any way other than to show either the source with some level of cleanup applied, or nothing at all.

What you'd presumably want to see instead is either:

- That the JVM spec gains the ability to treat enums as compile time constants (there is a marked difference; at the class level, constants are just stored verbatim, with their actual value, in the class file, whereas non-CTCs aren't stored; instead a `static {}` block is generated that generates these. For example, `public static final long STAMP = System.currentTimeMillis();` is turned into a class file that has a static init 'method' that runs that code - you can't reduce that to a constan). That's rather a big update to all of java just for the benefit of javadoc, which is weird.
- That the javadoc tool parts ways with the JVM spec and goes its own way on CTC. This seems annoying. Surely you'd want `public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = SomeOtherClass.DEFAULT_COLOR;` to work just as well (it does if those were ints!), so that makes `javadoc` complicated and inconsistent. Just not worth it.
- An option to tell javadoc to just take the source code of the initializer and render it verbatim (or with a light application of reformatting, perhaps) into the HTML.

That third one seems fair, something like:

```
/** {@showDefault} */
public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.RED;
```

but javadoc simply does not work that way.

### Okay, so how do I do this without repeating myself?

You can't. Sorry about that.

Comment: Appreciate your response but you use a lot of examples that aren't related to Enums which is what the topic is about. As far as I know Javadoc uses `javac`  to parse a source code file so it could very well know the difference between `<enum-class> DEFAULT_COLOR = <enum>` (i.e. can be rendered) vs `<enum-class> DEFAULT_COLOR = <expression>`  (i.e. cannot be rendered), exactly similar as today where it can distinguish between `int ZZZ = <constant expression>`  (will be rendered) vs `int ZZZ = <non-constant expression>`  (will not be rendered). Perhaps there's something about enums I've missed?

Comment: Ok, so basically it cannot be done with the current Javadoc and this was what the question was about. So I'll accept this answer. However, I still don't understand **why not ?**, especially with the "Refinement" I've added on the question. But to be fair that wasn't the question so I think this answer should get the award.

Comment: @peterh I explain why things work the way they do, and I do mention that enums work the same way as all the other examples. It even mentions the idea of 'updating' java's baked in notion of Compile Time Constant to upgrade it to enums. Maybe, but it just doesn't work that way, so unless you want to cheerlead this plan and go through the years+ effort of getting a JEP for it, __you just cannot do it__, and this post explains why not, in case you find that a frustrating answer.

Comment: Your refinement doesn't matter - and this is answered in this question: if `static final Color R = Color.RED;` works, but `static final Color R = SomeOtherClass.SOME_CONSTANT;` does not, that'd be bizarre, and inconsistent. And yet, for that to work, enums must become complete CTCs. Possible, but not simple, and not currently part of the java spec and not on the horizon. Thus, what you want isn't actually simple even if you think it is.